# How to update a textfield with data from perl script without reloading whole page?

Tags: html, perl, input

I have three input fields, in the first i enter an cardnumber in the second i enter the pin, after i entered both of the inputfields it should run an perl script which fills the third input field with the ammount of the card (the amount comes from the db with the perlscript).

Is there something like an afterupdate for the inputfields, which then starts the perlscript?
And is there anyway to fill the third inputfield without print the whole page again with the perlscript? Thanks for ya help!

Answer (score 3):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - its a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development

The [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur) event of the second input field should trigger an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request to your perl script that will return data you require and then populate the 3rd textfield with this data, without the need to reload the page.

I could write the code for you BUT you'll gain a much better understanding by trying it yourself.

If you get stuck - edit the question to include your code and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Obligatory "You should totally drop that and try jQuery" reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492

Comment: +1 for not writing the code for OP. -1 because blur on second field may need to be checked for whether first field was populated before AJAX call - pwd may be entered before uid by random user. +1 for good high level plan :)